# Route ONLY specific LAN through VPN

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn, linux-networking

I have ONE PC with two internal LANS. `192.168.10.4` is internal LAN and `192.168.42.2`is the ip that get it from my Raspberry. Raspberry connect via wifi from my wifi router, then run tor daemon and give me the address 192.168.42.2.Now I get the 192.168.42.2 from Raspberry. Then ,I am connecting to VPN with port on `TCP 443` with ovpn file.

Everything works fine but I don't want to connect when I use `192.168.10.4`, I want to block it. I am linux user and I am connecting in VPN with ovpn file via openvpn in mate environment.

I thought that I could do with `iptables` but I can't. So how can I route the traffic only at `192.168.42.2` then reject any other LANs. I am thinking that I can do it over ovpn file or route command via terminal.

Here is the output of `ip route`:

```
default via 10.7.7.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp33s0 proto static metric 100 
10.7.7.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.7.5 metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp33s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.10.0/28 dev enp33s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.3 metric 100 
217.23.3.91 via 192.168.10.1 dev enp33s0 proto static metric 100
```

Would you like to tell me how to do that? I am searched a lots of examples but I cannot understand.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you have an OpenVPN server with two NICs with IP addresses of `192.168.10.4` and `192.168.42.2`. For clients connecting to your server you want to prohibit access to the network containing `192.168.10.4` 
 and only allow them to access then network containing `192.168.42.2`. Am I getting this right?

Comment: No, It is not right. I have ONE pc with 2 lan. I use different internal ip. My goal is when I use 192.168.10.4 DO NOT allow to connect to nordvpn with port 443.I don't have openvpn server.

Answer (score 0):

Your output from `ip route` doesn't show anything about 192.168.42.2, so I assume that network is not up at the time you create that output.

Your VPN server seems to be reachable at `217.23.3.91 via 192.168.10.1`. Now your address on that interface seems to be `192.168.10.3`, which is not mentioned in your question.

One way to block outgoing traffic is that you accept all traffic to your VPN server and drop everything from 192.168.10.0/28 that isn't directed at the local subnet. The exception for the VPN server is needed otherwise you can't reach your VPN server to establish the VPN connection. If you get your address by DHCP, you might need an exception for that, too.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination 217.23.3.91 –-dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.10.0/28 ! --destination 192.168.10.0/28 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.10.0/28 --out-interface tun0 -j DROP
```

**Edit:**
Added explanation, changed to long options `-s --source` and `-d ----destination` are equivalent

The first command accepts a TCP connection to the server at 217.23.3.91 port 443. This should be your VPN server. If the VPN server has more addresses, you need a line for each address, or you specify and address range.

The `!` in the second command means "not". So every packet with source in 192.168.10.0/28 and destination not in 192.168.10.0/28 will be dropped.  According to your later comment this is not what you want.

The third command drops packets with source address in 192.168.10.0/28 that go to the interface tun0. tun0 is a common name for the interface that openvpn creates, of course you must verify that this is really the name of the VPN interface. Run the command `ip l` while your VPN is running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to use this command. I have a question for you.

Forward chain is for delivery packet for the same internal lan. My goal is for one pc only that change internal ip. Example: I want to connect nordvpn with port tcp 443 (ovpn file), when I use internal ip 192.168.42.2.

If the same pc has internal ip 192.168.10.4 and try again to connect the vpn , I want to block it. That's my goal.

Thank you

Comment: @mike I added a description of FORWARD to the text. It applies to all interfaces, not just lan interfaces. I'm not sure whether I understand you. At this point, it doesn't matter what port your VPN uses. OpenVPN will give you a tun interface (or maybe tap, depending on what you configured). Is the PC you want to block the VPN router, or is it another PC connected to the VPN router?

Comment: I don't have a vpn router. I never said that I have vpn router. I have one pc ONLY that connect to a vpn like nordvpn with internal ip 192.168.42.2 THE SAME pc change internal ip 192.168.10.4 and now I WANT to block when I use 192.168.10.4  internal ip address to connect to a vpn.

Comment: @mike If you don't have a router, the above command will not work. You should explain why you have two different addresses for a single PC. Or is the 192.168.42.2 the address you get on the VPN interface and 192.168.10.4 the address on the LAN interface? If you have a VPN with a single address, you don't have to do anything, it will not work for other address anyway.

Comment: The 192.168.10.4 is the lan inteface and 192.168.42.2 is the lan interface that get from raspaberry. If you need extra information , i will give you thank you ralf

Comment: @mike could you explain in more detail, preferably by editing the question? Why do you have two LAN interfaces, if you have just one PC? Now you mention a Raspberry. A Raspberry in this context is also a network device, so you have more than one network device and your VPN device may or may not route traffic from the Raspberry. So do you want the Raspberry blocked or enabled? As you say the different commands to block don't work, how exactly do you verify that?

Comment: I editied the question but I want to FORGET 192.168.42.2 then please you try tofocus in 192.168.10.4. I want to block 192.168.10.4 . How to do that? Do you want to show you route command or ip route show? Than k you very much

Comment: @mike you want to establish your VPN connection via TOR and not via your usual internet connection, am I seeing this right? Is your linux device in one subnet and the PI in another one which is being routed by your all-in-one router/wifi box? In your routing table I cannot see anything like `192.168.42.2`...

Comment: Sorry, fixed the order, it has to be "! -d" and not "-d !". More details would be helpful. Your PC is 192.168.10.3, that is consistent with the output above. What is 192.168.10.4? If PC and Raspberry are connected to the same router, why an address 192.168.42.2 from another address range?

Comment: I changed  to  ! -d and block everything. :( Rasbperry connect tor and give different ip .What information you want to give you

Comment: You wanted to block everything from 192.168.10.4, didn't you? Can you explain what you want to block and what you want to allow?

Comment: I want to block "ONLY  to connect on vpn" from 192.168.10.4 I want to allow regular traffic from 192.168.10.4 .

Comment: I think this line is correct iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.0/28 -d name of vpn --dport 443 -j REJECT . I appreciate  your help Ralf. Thank you very much

Comment: @mike did the command in your comment above solve the problem?

Comment: Yes It solved. Thank you very much. Would you like to tell me what does this iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.10.0/28 ! -d 192.168.10.0/28 -j DROP ? I don't understand what does ! before -d

Comment: I added an explanation. The command `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.0/28 -d name of vpn --dport 443 -j REJECT` should block your VPN tunnel.

Comment: I don't understand why the third command doesn't work. iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.10.0/28 --out-interface tun0 -j DROP

Comment: That command should block everything from 192.168.10.0/28 going to tun0. Can you run tcpdump on tun0 and verify that there is traffic that should be blocked?

Comment: I put tcpdump -i tun0 then show a lots of packets. I can login to vpn so why this iptables command does not work?

Comment: Do you want to block the VPN tunnel? Show some of the packets from tcpdump that you want blocked.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do I write tcpdump -i tun0 and I show you what is output?

Comment: Yes, you have some traffic that you want blocked. Show some or all of the packets that you want to have blocked.

Comment: You wrrote this line . iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.10.0/28 --out-interface tun0 -j DROP , but It doesn't work. Why ? It should work. Yes I want to block all traffic from tun0 to 192.168.10.0/28. I would like to ask what do you want to do to show you? tcpdum -i tun0 ????

Comment: You write "but It doesn't work". You know that because that exactly happens? Yes, show the output of "tcpdump -ns1500 -itun0", if that is an example of packets that go through, or if you are not sure.

Comment: 783354 IP 10.7.7.6.53600 > 74.125.200.94.443: 783354 IP 10.7.7.6.53600 > 74.125.200.94.443:  10.7.7.6.50108 > 216.239.34.21.80   216.239.34.21.80 > 10.7.7.6.50108:

Comment: Non of that is `192.168.10.4`, so how does it fit the packets you saw you want blocked?

Comment: When I connect to vpn I can use browser e-mail everything. I want to block to CONNECT TO VPN. I want to NOT  allow to CONNECT to VPN like this command. iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.0/28 -d name of vpn --dport 443 -j REJECT but I want to allow regular connection to 192.168.10.4

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Give one specific example of a connection you want blocked.

Comment: If I put this line iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.0/28 -d name of vpn --dport 443 -j REJECT, I am not able to connect to vpn. When I put YOUR third LINE ( iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.10.0/28 --out-interface tun0 -j DROP ) I am able to connect to vpn.so It does not work your third line. Why?

Comment: If you want to block the VPN connection itself, just don't start the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is when I use 192.168.10.4 DO NOT allow to connect to nordvpn with port 443

As you like to deny traffic originating from your localhost (*system* as stated in the graph) we need to take action on the `OUTPUT` chain.

[image]

This line will deny traffic from the source network (might need to adjust netmask) to one server (need to replace *IP address of target server* with the *actual IP address*) on TCP port 443.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d <IP address of target server> --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It doesn't work. Maybe ip route show can you help.default via 10.7.7.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp33s0 proto static metric 100 
10.7.7.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.7.5 metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp33s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.10.0/28 dev enp33s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.3 metric 100 
217.23.3.91 via 192.168.10.1 dev enp33s0 proto static metric 100

Comment: Append the output of `ip route` to your original post and format it as code, please. I am afraid it is not readable this way.

Comment: Kenvin I am sorry I dont understand. Would you like to explain me what does do you mean. I have a ovpn file (protonvpn) and I put your command above. But It doesn't work

Comment: I just wanted you to put the output you have in your comment in your Question, but I have edited it now. When it is peer reviewed, you will also be able to see it. So you ran the `iptables` command from above and you were still able to let packets flow towards the VPN server via the `192.168.10.0` network?

Comment: Yes I put your iptables command but  It does not blocked.  I am not sure if I put the correct destination to vpn. the vpn is protonvpn and I put the 185.70.40.231 for destination. Thank you kevin.